# How to conditionally set php session cookie within php-fpm www.conf?

Tags: php, configuration, php-fpm, apache-2.4

I need to set PHP session cookie domain dynamically using php-fpm configuration, pseudo code like this:

```
<If "%{HTTP_HOST} !~ /[0-9]/">
  php_value[session.cookie_domain] = ".mysite.com"
</If>
```

The `<If>` directive works in Apache configuration. However, I need this in `www.conf`, which looks like a `php.ini` file. How to do it?

Answer (score 1):

**First step:** take a look over PHP-FPM pools (ex.: http://blog.chrismeller.com/configuring-and-optimizing-php-fpm-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-or-debian)

**Second step:** You can create a php-fpm pool for each domain you're hosting (ex. mysite.com)

```
In PHP-FPM config:
-----------------
Copy “www” pool config file (www.conf located in /etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/ on my system) saving it as mysite.conf and changing:
    - the [www] label at the top of the file to [mysite]
    - the port in the “listen” directive to 9001 (from the deault of 9000)
    - add a new line: php_value[session.cookie_domain] = ".mysite.com"
```

**Third step:** Create a new listener in Nginx for the new site (mysite.com)

```
In Nginx config:
----------------
Create a new vhost for mysite.com. and send PHP requests via port 9001 rather than the default port 9000
```

**Forth step:** restart PHP-FPM (on my system: /etc/init.d/php-fpm restart) and Nginx (on my system: /etc/init.d/nginx restart)

*Credits go to: https://thedotproduct.org/setting-or-overriding-php-configuration-in-php-fpm-pool-configurations/*

Comment: Thanks for the info. But I am on Apache 2.4, not Nginx.

Comment: it will work for Apache as well. The important stuff is to create a php-fpm pool for each site that needs a custom php config. Take a look at: http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/PHP-FPM